# Plotting the solution of a differential equation,

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, mathematical-optimization

Having a differential equation:

```
{Derivative[1][T][R] == (-1 + (
    1 + Sqrt[-0.25 + 2 r + 0.13 r^3])/(
    1 - Sqrt[-0.25 + 2 r + 0.13 r^3]))/(
   1 + (1 + Sqrt[-0.25 + 2 r + 0.13 r^3])/(
    1 - Sqrt[-0.25 + 2 r + 0.13 r^3]))}
```

If initial conditions are required, these could be: T[0.15] == 0, and range of R is: [0.15, 20] 
 I need plotting of the solution of above equation in $T, R $ coordinates.
But since the above expression is depending on $r$ also, for that purpose I may solve another differential equation,given below to get expression for r:

```
{t'[r] == 
    r^3/(Sqrt[
       0.13 r^3 + 2 r - (0.5)^2] (-0.13 r^3 + r^2 - 2 r + (0.5)^2))} 

ICs: t[0.134] == 0  and r=[ 0.134, 20] (range of r)
```

I would like to mention here that these two equations are linked in the sense that I have changed the co-ordinates from (t,r) to (T, R), how these coordinates are linked, I have that information as well, but the final expression of differential equation in new coordinates is as given in equation 1. I couldnt get explicit expression of r in terms of T and R, so $r$ is appearing in differential equation of new coordinates.

Comment: First, theoretically both equations are solvable symbolically in terms of Elliptic integrals. Second, you seem to be interested in computing `t[r]` and then finding its inverse, right? Third, is the second equation a transformation of the first? As the question is currently written, it's not at all clear why it should be included. The capital `R` looks like a typo, since the equation has no `R` in it. Finally, maybe you're looking for `Interpolation`, to make use of your data.

Comment: Please clarify the question. I see you have accepted bbgodfrey's answer, but I cannot tell whether it is correct or not -- the question is so unclear. As a consequence I cannot upvote his answer and reward him for the work he has put into it, assuming it turns out to be correct. On the face of it, it seems improbable that if $u = t(r)$, one would let $r = u = t(r)$ and rename the argument $R$; since both equations contain the form `Sqrt[-0.25 + 2 r + 0.13 r^3]`, it seems the $r$'s ought to be the same.

Comment: @Michel E2 , I have edited the post, please let me know if it is clear now? I hope so.

Comment: Thank you very much. That is considerably clearer. There is one point that still confuses me. As I understand it, the first equation cannot be solved because it is in terms of $r$ and not $R$; so we need to put $r$ in terms of $R$ or even $(T,R)$, yes? You know how $(t,r)$ is connected to $(T,R)$: Presumably you mean you have a function $(T,R)=\phi(t,r)$ (or its inverse). `NDSolve` solves the second equation to give $t=t(r)$. Then we'd have to solve numerically the system $(T,R)=\phi(t(r),r)$ for $r$ in terms of $(T,R)$. Correct? You'd need to tell us $\phi$ (or its inverse), if so.

Comment: @Michael E2 I have R= Exp[r*/beta]Cosh[t/beta] where $\beta= some constant$ and r*= Integral[(r^2 dr)/(-\alpha r^3 + r^2-2m r + Q^2)], so I need to solve this integral for getting r*, and that would give me R ultimately. Similarly, T=Exp[r*/beta]Sinh[t/beta]. and here \beta has some relationship of the roots of the cubic polynomial $-\alpha r^3 + r^2-2m r + Q^2)$, where Q is charge, m is mass and $\alpha$ is a small positive number, so arbitrary values could be set for these parameters., the thing which complicates this whole story is, I get the solution of integral for r* in complicated form

Comment: If I consider the other way, that I just plot the solution of differential equation, by specifying the suitable range of $r$, would it give me some out put (Plot T, R)? e.g, if i say: ,$ T = T /. First@ 
NDSolve[{Derivative[1][T][ 
R] == (-1 + (1 + Sqrt[-0.25 + 2 r + 0.13 r^3])/(1 - 
Sqrt[-0.25 + 2 r + 0.13 r^3]))/(1 + (1 + 
Sqrt[-0.25 + 2 r + 0.13 r^3])/(1 - 
Sqrt[-0.25 + 2 r + 0.13 r^3])), T[0.15] == 0}, {R, 0.15, 
20}, T]; ParametricPlot[{T, R}, {r, 0.134, 20}, PlotRange -> All]$ there is some error message on mathematica file, please let me know what is wrong with this approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is a bit unclear, because you need `r` for your first expression, but you obtain `u` in the second expression.  Therefore, I assume that `u` is to replace `r` in the first expression.  If not, please say so.

With that assumption,

```
u = t /. First@NDSolve[{t'[r] == r^3/(Sqrt[0.13 r^3 + 2 r - (0.5)^2] (-0.13 r^3 + r^2 - 
    2 r + (0.5)^2)), t[0.134] == 0}, t, {r, 0.134, 20}];
Plot[u[r], {r, 0.134, 20}]
```

[image: u]

```
T = T /. First@NDSolve[{Derivative[1][T][R] == (-1 + (1 + Sqrt[-0.25 + 2 u[R] + 0.13 u[R]^3])/(1 - 
    Sqrt[-0.25 + 2 u[R] + 0.13 u[R]^3]))/(1 + (1 + Sqrt[-0.25 + 2 u[R] + 0.13 u[R]^3])/(1 - 
    Sqrt[-0.25 + 2 u[R] + 0.13 u[R]^3])), T[0.15] == 0}, T, {R, 0.15, 20}];
Plot[{Re[T[r]], Im[T[r]]}, {r, 0.15, 20}]
```

[image: T]

Note that `T` is complex, with `Im[T]` much larger than `Re[T]`.

`Im[T]` also can be plotted against `u` (labeled `R` in the plot):

```
ParametricPlot[{u[R], Im[T[R]]}, {R, 0.15, 20}, AspectRatio -> 1, 
 AxesLabel -> {"R", "Im[T]"}, PlotRange -> {{-2.5, 0}, {0, 2}}]
```

[image: Parametric Plot]

Comment: @ bbgodfrey Yes you are right, in fact i just call that expression as $u$, otherwise i will get t[r] from that expression. so I think we can replace u and t but not u and r??

Comment: @ bbgodfrey Second thing is, I was really in need of plotting the results of the first differential equation of my post, in $T, R$ coordinates, but I see you have plotted real and Imaginary parts of T only. Please guide me how to get plotting of T versus R? (here r is involved, which could be obtained from second equation, I hope you understand my point?)

Comment: Do you wish `Im[T]` vs. `R`?

Comment: @ bbgodfrey Thanks a lot for your cooperation, really helpfull comments. So do you mean that T is a complex number? How do you know about it? I mean I could not get any result when I give command for ParametricPlot[{u[R], T[R]}, {R, 0.15, 20}], please remove my confusion.

Comment: bbgodfrey I see there is a serious confusion with variables, I am extremely sorry for inconvenience, so I just want to remove that extra introduced variable u, I hope you wouldnt mind if I edit the post in this sense, I am waiting for your valuable comment on my edited post, please make the corresponding changes in your comments, if possible..

Comment: @ bbgodfrey parallel to your work, if I just use following command:$ t = t /. First@
    NDSolve[{t'[r] == 
       r^3/(Sqrt[
           0.13 r^3 + 2 r - (0.5)^2] (-0.13 r^3 + r^2 - 
            2 r + (0.5)^2)), t[0.134] == 0}, t, {r, 0.134, 20}];
Plot[t[r], {r, 0.134, 20}]$ this is fine, I will get plot of (t,r). But how would I work with the next part, I mean as you have replaced variable $r$ by $u[R]$, here R is different from $r$. So my question is how to deal with that $r$? Finally I want plotting in (T,R). Waiting for your kind reply.

Comment: Proceeding from your last comment back, I presume that you actually used `{r,0.134,20}`  rather than `r,0.134,20` to obtain and plot `t`, which appears to be identical to the quantity `u` that I obtained earlier.  You now have four variables, `T,R,t,r`, which is one too many.  It is for that reason that I surmised that my `u` (your `t`) was equal to `r` in the first expression.  If that is not so, then you must provide an alternative relationship among the four variables.  It is important that you address the comments by @MichaelE2, and your edit does not do so adequately.

Comment: Alternatively, I suppose that all four quantities could be distinct, in which case two of them could be expressed in terms of the other two.  Alternatively, if @MichaelE2 is correct that `R` and `r` are the same, then the equations can be solved by inverting the second solution to obtain `r[t]` and substituting it into the first equation.  Finally, from the form of the equations, I would not be surprised if they could be solved in terms of Elliptic Integrals, as @MichaelE2 suggested.  In that case, solving the equations analytically would be best, in order to handle branch cuts explicitly.